# GET-параметр в контроллере Yii 2

Tags: php, yii2, get

Можно ли передать GET-параметр в `action` контроллера при клике на ссылку?

Код контроллера:

```
public function actionFilter() {
    $categoryId = Yii::$app->request->get('id');

    return $this->render('index', compact('categoryId'));
}
```

Сама ссылка в шаблоне:

```
<?= Html::a('Horror', ['site/filter'], [
        'data' => [
          'method' => 'get',
          'params' => [
            'id' => 'horror',
          ],
        ]
]); ?>
```

`action` контроллера даже не вызывается, но при POST-запросе всё работает корректно.

Comment: А как выглядит ссылка в html? И какой запрос уходит на сервер при клике?

Comment: Ссылка выглядит вот так: <a href="/bs/web/index.php?r=site%2Ffilter" data-method="get" data-params="{"id":"horror"}">Horror</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так заработало: `<?= Html::a('Horror', ['site/filter', 'id'=>'horror']); ?>`